# How to Get record from controller to Ajax laravel 5.2

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, laravel

Greetings and respect I want when I log records in the database table to be updated, but unfortunately I do not do anything that can not fetch the ID and pour into AJAX and AJAX, I wanna relationship between the controller and the amount I make read from the database and table.

my Controller:

```
    public function index()
{
    $category = Category::all();
    return view('admin.category', compact('category'));
}
public function indexAjax(messageRequest $request){
    $id=$request->id;
    $category=Category::where('id',$id)->first();
    $data=array('data'=>$category);
    return $data;
}
public function create(messageRequest $request)
{
    try {
        Category::create($request->all());
        return response()->json(array('sms'=>'save'));
    }catch (Exception $e){
        return response()->json(array('err'=>'error'));
    }
}
```

my Route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
Route::auth();
Route::get('category',['uses'=>'categoryController@index']);
});
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
Route::auth();
Route::get('categoryAjax',    ['as'=>'categoryAjax','uses'=>'categoryController@indexAjax']);
});
```

script:

```
            <script>
            $('#submit').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var data = $('#create').serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: '{!! URL::route('category') !!}',
                    data: data,
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data.sms);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert(data.err);
                    }
                });
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '{!! URL::route('categoryAjax') !!}',
                    async: false,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: data,
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data.data);
                    }
                });
            });
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
        </script>
```

I changed `alert(data.data)` to `alert('hi)` but not run :(
changed:

```
                    $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '{!! URL::route('categoryAjax') !!}',
                    async: false,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: data,
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert('hi');
                    }
                });
```

my Ajax method POST:

```
                    $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: '{!! URL::route('category') !!}',
                    data: data,
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data.sms);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert(data.err);
                    }
                });
```

my controller POST method:

```
    public function create(messageRequest $request)
{
    try {
        Category::create($request->all());
        return response()->json(array('sms'=>'save'));
    }catch (Exception $e){
        return response()->json(array('err'=>'error'));
    }
}
```

my route POST method:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
Route::auth();
Route::post('category', ['as' => 'category',  'uses' => 'categoryController@create']);
});
```

Comment: You defined Route::get('category',['uses'=>'categoryController@index'])
And why you make ajax type: 'post' ? This makes no sense at all.

Comment: Post method to send data and receive connection to the controller was added time.Try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by This Code my Problem is Solved.But remove `$.get` from my script and run with POST method.

```
    public function create(messageRequest $request)
{
    try {
        $category = Category::create($request->all())->id;
        return response()->json(['id'=>$category]);
    }catch (Exception $e){
        return response()->json(array('err'=>'error'));
    }
}
```

by this code return record ID in alert.

Answer (score 2):

In the Laravel 5.2, the middleware has web, api, and auth.
If you want to use ajax sent data, you will use the api middleware with token.
You can see this reference:

- https://mattstauffer.co/blog/multiple-authentication-guard-drivers-including-api-in-laravel-5-2
- https://gistlog.co/JacobBennett/090369fbab0b31130b51

First, Add an api_token to user:

The first think you need to do is to add an api_token column to your users table. If you are just starting your application you can likely get away with modifying the user migration that ships with Laravel to include your new column.

```
// add this to your users_table migration
$table->string('api_token', 60)->unique();
```

Controller:

```
public function upload()
{
    return view('uploads.upload', ['api_token' => Auth::user()->api_token]);
}
```

View:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        'use strict';

        var url = '/api/photos?api_token={{ $api_token }}';

        // Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
        $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
            // xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
            url: url
        });      
</script>
```

Route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api']], function () {
    Route::post('api/photos', 'FileController@storeApi');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your kindness does not trouble the rest of the code?

Comment: I'm not sure. But you can modify the route and try it. O______O

Comment: I changed my route, but still failed.

Comment: can you check the indexAjax have work? try to echo something in the function?

Comment: this is not my question :(

Comment: can you set a alert() between the two ajax function,  and set a alert() before the first ajax function，i want to check where are stuck.